# /etc/environment doesn't apply to all users on Debian Jessie

Tags: debian, environment-variables

I've just installed Debian 8.6. I want to set http proxy environment variables for all users, so I edited `/etc/environment` following the guide on [Debian's wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/EnvironmentVariables). However, after rebooting, only root user's environment variables are set.

This is my `/etc/environment` content:

```
http_proxy=http://localhost:8123/
https_proxy=http://localhost:8123/
ftp_proxy=http://localhost:8123/
no_proxy="localhost,127.0.0.1,localaddress,.localdomain.com"
HTTP_PROXY=http://localhost:8123/
HTTPS_PROXY=http://localhost:8123/
FTP_PROXY=http://localhost:8123/
NO_PROXY="localhost,127.0.0.1,localaddress,.localdomain.com"
```

And I check the result by:

```
echo $http_proxy
```

When logging in as root with `sudo su`, it gives me right result(`http://localhost:8123/`), but when using normal user the variables are not set. I also check all environment variables with `env`.

**Update:**

Here come more tests.

I add `SET_BY_ETC_ENVIRONMENT="hello"` to `/etc/environment`, `export SET_BY_ETC_PROFILE="hello"` to `/etc/profile` and `export SET_BY_HOME_PROFILE="hello"` to `/home/perqin/.profile`.

And here's the result:

```
user   | login via                    | SET_BY_ETC_ENVIRONMENT | SET_BY_ETC_PROFILE | SET_BY_HOME_PROFILE
-------|------------------------------|------------------------|--------------------|--------------------
perqin | GUI                          | no                     | no                 | no
root   | GUI                          | no                     | no                 | no
perqin | sudo su in terminal from GUI | yes                    | no                 | no
root   | su in terminal from GUI      | yes                    | no                 | no
perqin | ssh                          | yes                    | yes                | yes
root   | ssh                          | yes                    | yes                | no
```

So `profile` is only executed in ssh login. And NONE of them are applied in GUI! I am using Debian 8.6 with LXDE desktop environment.

**Update 12.14**

The output of `grep pam_env /etc/pam.conf /etc/pam.d/*` is as below:

```
/etc/pam.d/atd:auth required    pam_env.so
/etc/pam.d/cron:# Read environment variables from pam_env's default files, /etc/environment
/etc/pam.d/cron:# and /etc/security/pam_env.conf.
/etc/pam.d/cron:session       required   pam_env.so
/etc/pam.d/cron:session       required   pam_env.so envfile=/etc/default/locale
/etc/pam.d/lightdm:# Load environment from /etc/environment and ~/.pam_environment
/etc/pam.d/lightdm:auth      required pam_env.so envfile=/etc/default/locale
/etc/pam.d/lightdm-autologin:# Load environment from /etc/environment and ~/.pam_environment
/etc/pam.d/lightdm-autologin:auth      required pam_env.so envfile=/etc/default/locale
/etc/pam.d/lightdm-greeter:# Load environment from /etc/environment and ~/.pam_environment
/etc/pam.d/lightdm-greeter:auth      required pam_env.so envfile=/etc/default/locale
/etc/pam.d/login:# file /etc/security/pam_env.conf.
/etc/pam.d/login:session       required   pam_env.so readenv=1
/etc/pam.d/login:session       required   pam_env.so readenv=1 envfile=/etc/default/locale
/etc/pam.d/polkit-1:session       required   pam_env.so readenv=1 user_readenv=0
/etc/pam.d/polkit-1:session       required   pam_env.so readenv=1 envfile=/etc/default/locale user_readenv=0
/etc/pam.d/sshd:# /etc/security/pam_env.conf.
/etc/pam.d/sshd:session    required     pam_env.so # [1]
/etc/pam.d/sshd:session    required     pam_env.so user_readenv=1 envfile=/etc/default/locale
/etc/pam.d/su:# file /etc/security/pam_env.conf.
/etc/pam.d/su:session       required   pam_env.so readenv=1
/etc/pam.d/su:session       required   pam_env.so readenv=1 envfile=/etc/default/locale
```

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/664169/what-is-the-difference-between-etc-environment-and-etc-profile

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro I also tried adding export lines in /etc/profile, but I still can't get the environment variables set.

Comment: Are your users using the default `bash` shell?

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro Yes. Running `echo $SHELL` gives me `/bin/bash`.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro I even add them to ~/. profile but also fails. Source the file manually does set the variables so it should not be the mistakes of the script...

Comment: Can you reproduce this with another account? Can you reproduce this if you move your dot files out of the way? Have you made changes to the PAM configuration? The problem is with something unusual somewhere that you aren't telling us about (possibly because you aren't aware of it), and there are too many possibilities to list.

Comment: Works for me with `ssh` logins as an ordinary user on Debian 7.8 and 8.0. I'm looking for an 8.6 nearby.

Comment: How do you log in as your normal user? GUI? ssh? local console?

Comment: @Gilles I just installed Debian so there should not be something that was modified by mistake... some tests are appended to the question description.

Comment: @roaima `ssh` login does work, but GUI and terminal in GUI doesn't work not matter using normal or root user. Some tests are added to the question description.

Comment: Which display manager are you using? What is the output of `grep pam_env /etc/pam.conf /etc/pam.d/*`? What about a text mode console login (Ctrl+Alt+F1)?

Comment: @Gilles The display manager is LightDM and the output is pasted in the question description. The console login result is the same as that of ssh login.

Comment: That looks like a bug in either LightDM or LXDE, or in the way they're set up by Debian. Can you try a different display manager, a different account using LXDE, and a different account using a different session type (e.g. a different desktop environment)?

Comment: @Gilles Hey, you saved the day! I change the DM to SLiM and the `/etc/environment` is loaded. I googled around about the environment variables issue of LightDM but doesn't find anything helpful, so I will stay at SLiM now:) Thank you (and all the others who tried to help me) a lot!